# Datetime Value change when passing to apex from LWC

Tags: apex, javascript, lightning-web-components

I am passing value in a field of dateTime type and sending it from lightning web component to Apex for record creation. The value of field in Component is "Sun Jan 03 2021 05:00:00 GMT+0530" but if i pass the value to a method in apex and print the same value in developer console the value gets deducted by 5:30 hrs and is printed as " 2021-01-02 23:30:00". But once the record is saved with this field value the value of the field is again "3 jan 2021 5:00:00". Can somebody explain what is happening while value passes from lwc to apex and why. My User timezone is (GMT+05:30) India Standard Time (Asia/Kolkata) but even if i change my timezone to gmt+0 the above scenario remains the same.

for more information i am calculating datetime value in js in following way

```
 Date.prototype.addDays = function (days) {
        var date = new Date(this.valueOf());
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + days)
        return date;
    }

    function msToTime(duration) {

        var seconds = Math.floor((duration / 1000) % 60),
            minutes = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60)) % 60),
            hours = Math.floor((duration / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
        hours = (hours < 10) ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = (minutes < 10) ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = (seconds < 10) ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        return hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

    }


   days=1
   var datetimefield = new Date(this.datefield.toString().concat('T', msToTime(this.timefield))).addDays(days);
```

Answer (score 3):

You're using non-standard time formatting, so strange things will happen. Just pass in the date directly, or use toISOString() instead of toString(). You shouldn't be trying to do custom logic, as that tends to get things wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Datetime values are stored as UTC and are converted to and from the user's time zone in apex. However the value is debug logged as, and JSON serialised to, UTC.

Once the value is in the database, it will be 2021-01-02 23:30:00. How it is handled in your LWC JavaScript comes down to how you pass it, what you do with it and whether you use standard Salesforce components to handle it. Since JSON serialisation is used when sending data to the LWC client you will receive the values in ISO format and as UTC.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you are handling it correctly (passing timezone identifier). However, I agree with @sfdcfox, using standard methods is always recommended to avoid any surprises (especially for handling boundary conditions).

In your code, javascript (LWC) is sending datetime value to Apex, along with timezone identifier (GMT+0530). Due to this, apex interprets the datetime value as GMT+0530 value.

Internally all datetime values are stored in salesforce as GMT values. So, the given value is converted to GMT i.e. deducts 5hrs 30 min from it. Now, when you print its value in debug logs, it is displaying value, as per GMT time. If you use **datetime.format()** method, it'll show value in your timezone.

Comment: makes sense ...is there any way i can convert the value in datetime field according to user timezone not only as string but actual datetime in user timezone.

Comment: Can you explain in a more details, what your are trying to achieve? Salesforce automatically concerts and displays date time to user based on user's time zone settings.